# New GDR3 "close button" doesn't terminate the app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

So I was debugging my app on my phone with Visual Studio attached. I've decided to close the app using the new close button introduced in GDR3. At this point the app has disappeared from the screen and quick switch, but Visual Studio was still attached.
Does that mean that the new close button doesn't actually close the app? What does it do then? Tombstoning it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application is killed. Visual Studio stays attached to help you debug background tasks, if any, and alternative ways of starting your app (through a pinned tile for instance). The same thing happens when you exit the app "normally" by pressing the back button multiple times.